# Android: getting different file size on the same file

Tags: android, database, file, size

I download the database file to Android storage. I am confused why the querying file size is different after opening the database. After downloading, it returns "size".After opening, it returns "size on disk".

```
    //download database file to storage
     ...(the content length from server is 52224)

    //query size
    databaseFile = new File(DBGlassConfig.getDatabasePath());
    long sizeBeforeLoading = databaseFile.length(); // 52224

    //open database
    if (databaseHandler == null)
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

    //query size
    databaseFile = new File(DBGlassConfig.getDatabasePath());
    long sizeAfterLoading = databaseFile.length(); // 53248


//open database
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            db = 
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DBGlassConfig.getDatabasePath(), null);
            }
```

Comment: You could have said that 1024 bytes were added.

Comment: Try again after closing the database.

Comment: Thanks! I try to diff them. SQLiteDatabase really revise the file.